# Program in 8085 Microprocessor

Tags: microprocessors, 8085

There are N bytes stored from m/m location 2500H. The value of N is stored in 2400H.How can I write an 8085 program to interchange (irrespective of the bit value) the bit Di with Dj for all bytes. The values of i=4 and j=0

Answer (score 1):

Nobody wants to do your homework for you. That being said, here's how you can interchange i-th bit of an 1-byte data with the j-th bit.

First let's revisit the bitwise logical operators and their usages. Suppose we want to know whether the 4-th bit is set, we take a bit mask `0000 1000`  (i.e. `08H`) and `AND` it with the data. To clear the 2nd bit we take the bit mask `1111 1101` (i.e. `FDH`) and `AND` it with data. Whereas, to set the 6-th bit we take a bit mask `0000 0010` (i.e. `02H`) and `OR` it with the data. To complement of flip the 4-th bit we take a bit mask `0000 1000`  (i.e. `08H`) and `XOR` it with the data.

Assuming the actual data is in register D, thus to exchange the 2nd bit with the 4-th one we may write:

```
MVI A, 08H    ;i-th bit
ORI 02H       ;j-th bit
ANI D         ;only 2nd and 4bit of the data survives
JPE SKIP      ;if both bits are same (both 0 or both 1) no exchange required
;if not we need a swap, which is this case can be done by flipping the both 
MOV A,D       ;bring back the data again
XRI 08H       ;flip the i-th bit
XRI 02H       ;flip the j-th bit
SKIP: MOV D,A ;put the data back to D
```

The bit mask canbe programmatically generated with appropritate number of shifts (or rotate without carry). And repeating this process on all of the `n` bytes would complete the required task.